# Referencing data from sheet one to sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I have a large spread sheet with multiple pages, columns and rows on each page.

on page Teams, I have row 3 column B as rider #12, and Column C as Time:

I need Column C,row 3 to display the time of the rider# from B3 from page Master Score Sheet.  On master score sheet, rider Numbers are in Column A and their times are displayed in column W.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! This question does not appear to be about programming as defined in the Help Center, and is thereby off topic for this site. You will probably be more likely to find help on an excel forum, or by googling something like "How do I reference data from one sheet to another in excel?" I hope you find your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Sergy S has it right, you might just need a little more detail.

Here is a screenshot of the 'Teams' Tab:
This is the formula in cell C2:

```
=INDEX('Master Score Sheet'!W:W,MATCH(Teams!B2,'Master Score Sheet'!A:A,0))
```

[image: Screenshot(1)]

Here is a screenshot of the 'Master Score Sheet' Tab:
[image: Screenshot(2)]

Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Comment: That's it, Thanks Guys

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Stick index and match formula in column c3 in your teams sheet
Like this: =index (referenceSheetname (A:W), match (referenceSheetname(A:A),teamsSheetname.B3,0),26)
Replace sheetnames with exact worksheetnames of your teams sheet and reference sheet where data is stored
Thanks
Serge

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the formula keeps giving me errors that I can't figure out how to correct.

Comment: Hey what error are you getting?#N/A or #VALUE?You need to nake sure your sheet names are right. Else post it here. Will check it out.